# Improving a suggested edit hangs when the original post is removed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

Scenario:

- A suggested edit is made to a post (question or answer)
- User X review the suggested edit above.
- In the time user X is reading the suggested edit, the author of the post remove the post
- User X clicks <kbd>Improve</kbd> and waits - **nothing is loaded and no error message**.

At this point, user X is confused. He later found out the post is removed.

I think it is better to shown some kind of message to the user to inform them that the post has been removed.

Comment: User X is also often confused when clicking Improve, and suddenly all the problems are gone. It takes some time to realize that user Y has also clicked Improve and already fixed the post.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean that the post being edited was *deleted*, i.e. it 404s when you link to it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few times and was unable to reproduce this. I tried improving a post, while deleting it mid-improvement, and got this error message:

> [image]

(I concede that this isn't the most helpful or accurate message, but at least it's something.)

If you're able to recall any additional details surround the bug, such as the exact post in question, we may be able to debug further. Sorry about that.

Comment: It was a month ago, and the question itself is deleted, so I don't think I can recover it. There are probably development happening during the time that fixes this bug (?)